# How to loop over stacks of lists being multiplied in chunks

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator, slice

I have multiple lists such as `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, each containing 10 list elements (numbers). Then I have two other lists, namely `c_a` and `c_b`, which are of equal length e.g. containing 3 elements. I wanted to multiply elements of lists `x1`, `x2` and `x3` in chunks with those in `c_a` and `c_b` as shown below;

```
    x_1[0:3]=[i*c_a[0]**2 for i in x_1[0:3]]
    x_1[3:6]=[i*c_b[0]**2 for i in x_1[3:6]]
    x_1[6:10]=[i*c_a[0]*c_b[0] for i in x_1[6:10]]
```

I now desire to embed this multiplication in a loop such that the names of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` and  index of `c_a[index]` and `c_b[index]` change iteratively. I look forward to your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the lists in another list. Then use `zip()` to loop over this list along with the lists `c_a`, `c_b`, and `c_b_Ni`.

```
for l, a, Ni, b in zip([x1, x2, x3], c_a, c_b_Ni, c_b):
    l[0:3]=[i*a**2 for i in l[0:3]]
    l[3:6]=[i*Ni**2 for i in l[3:6]]
    l[6:10]=[i*a*b for i in l[6:10]]
```